# Why redirect not working after uploading video on Vimeo using API?

Tags: php, vimeo-api

I have a small problem with uploading video to Vimeo using their api. I have installed older version 2.0 through composer because my application is still working on php 5.6. I will update it soon. When I start my php file to upload video, I see loading circle on tab and it never finish, just keeps loading. Video is uploaded successfully, but it won't execute header command from file.

This is my simple code:

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Vimeo\Vimeo;

$client = new Vimeo("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxx");

$file_name = "video123456.mp4";
$uri = $client->upload($file_name, array(
  "name" => "Test video",
  "description" => "Test 2"
));

header("Location: https://google.rs");
//echo "Your video URL is: " . $uri;
```

Comment: apply `exit;` after `header("Location: https://google.rs");` and check

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie I have tried but still not working. It just keeps loading.

Comment: There is a full example for uploading a video with their PHP SDK: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/example/upload.php

Follow this example (incl. try/catch blocks) to find out whats wrong with your implementation!